visual studioの設定？がわかりません
二つ質問があります
・visual studioをインストールしたときにvisual studio installarしかpcに入ってきません。
そこを開くとvisual studioを起動するボタンがあるのですが、visual studio自体のアプリケーションはないのでしょうか？
インストールしてデスクトップにおいて、それをおしたらすぐにvisual studioが起動できる環境ができたらよいのですが。。。
・プログラムを開始できません。指定されたファイルを見つけられません。
というエラーが出てくるのですが、
最後の方には￥debug￥421.exeというのが記述されておりました。
そこでdebugファイルの中を見てみると421.exeはなく、画像のようなファイルがありました
この場合どうすればよいですか？


例えば最初の質問ではこんなインストール解説記事の何処までを実行したがその通りにならないとか Visual Studio のインストール, Visual Studioの始め方。インストールから使い方まで。※2019/2022無料版, Visual Studio Community 2022 のインストール（Windows 上） 、2つ目の質問では何のプログラムを開始するためにどのような操作をしてそのエラーメッセージが通知されたのか等の詳細を追記してください。そもそもこのサイトは1つの記事に1つの質問が推奨されています。性質が違って関連の無い2つの質問ならば、それぞれ独立の質問記事を立ててください。

それともこちらの一般的なQ&A記事の内容を応用してみれば良いのでは？ アプリやフォルダーをデスクトップまたはタスク バーにピン留めする, [Windows 11] デスクトップにショートカットアイコンを作成する方法を教えてください。

Visual Studio に特化した例ならこちらの記事ですね。環境設定(Visual Studio 2022編)_2

一問一答形式ですので質問を分離してください。後者が 構造体のメンバ変数が参照できない で扱われているのであればこちらからは消してください。現状２つ回答が付いていますがいずれも前者にしか答えられておらず、質問が分断されて問題が解決しません。

1つ目の質問について
Visual Studio 自身にそれ以上の設定等はありません。
使いやすくするためにはWindowsの共通的な機能を応用して個々に工夫することです。
コメントで紹介した以下の記事の内容が当てはまるでしょう。
環境設定(Visual Studio 2022編)_2

画面左下(タスクバーに並んだ左端)の「Windowsアイコン」をクリックして「スタートメニュー」を表示する


メニュー右上の「すべてのアプリ」をクリックし、表示が変わったらスクロールダウンしていくと「V」で始まるアプリのリストの中に「Visual Studio 2022」があるので、これをクリックすれば起動します。
(@y_waiwaiさんの回答内容ですね)


上記紹介記事では、そのスタートメニューに表示された「Visual Studio 2022」をドラッグ＆ドロップしてデスクトップ上にコピーすることでデスクトップにショートカットを作っています。

他にはそのスタートメニューに表示された「Visual Studio 2022」をマウスで右クリックすることで表示されるコンテクストメニューの一番上に「スタートにピン留めする」を選べばスタートメニューが表示されたときのピン留め済みアイコンの(Visual Studio Installerと同様の)並びに「Visual Studio 2022」が表示されるようになります。

あるいはコンテクストメニューの二番目にある「詳細」をクリックして表示されるメニューにある「タスクバーにピン留めする」を選べばタスクバー上にアイコンが表示され、スタートメニューやデスクトップよりも素早く「Visual Studio 2022」を起動することが出来るようになります。




2つ目の質問について
おそらく対象の421.exeファイルを消去したか別の所に移動させたか、あるいはビルド結果としての421.exeの格納先と、デバッグ/実行対象としての421.exeのパス指定が違っている可能性が考えられます。
次に行われた質問 構造体のメンバ変数が参照できない と対象が同じかもしれないと考えても、ビルドでエラーが発生している間はデバッグ情報用の421.pdbファイルも出来ない(ビルド時にいったん両方とも消去される)はずですので、ビルドは出来ていそうです。
プロジェクトのプロパティを開いて、何かそれらのパス指定におかしなことが無いか確認してみてください。
細かいところまで確認するのが面倒ならば、いったん各ファイル/フォルダも含めたプロジェクト全体を削除して新しく作り直せば、デフォルト状態になるでしょう。

Visual Studio 2022 は、デフォルトでは、以下のパスにインストールされます。
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\<エディション>\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
このファイルは存在しますか？なければ、インストールに失敗しているのではないでしょうか？
インストールに失敗している場合、再度インストールをやり直してみてください。

Windowsボタンを押して、すべてのプログラムを開くとそこにありますよ
